# Minimum Steps To 1

Tags: python, dictionary, dynamic-programming

Given a positive integer 'n', find and return the minimum number of steps that 'n' has to take to get reduced to 1. You can perform any one of the following 3 steps:

1. Subtract 1 from it. (n = n - ­1)
2. If n is divisible by 2, divide by 2.( if n % 2 == 0, then n = n / 2)
3. If n is divisible by 3, divide by 3. (if n % 3 == 0, then n = n / 3)

Input format :

> The first and the only line of input contains an integer value, 'n'.

Output format :

> Print the minimum number of steps.

Constraints :

> 1 <= n <= 10 ^ 6 
> Time Limit: 1 sec

**Following is Code**

```
from sys import maxsize as MAX_VALUE 


dic = {}
def countMinStepsToOne(n) :
    if n == 1:
        return 0
    if n % 3 == 0:
        if n/3 not in dic:
            dic[n/3] = countMinStepsToOne(n/3)
    if n % 2 == 0:
        if n/2 not in dic:
            dic[n/2] = countMinStepsToOne(n/2)
    if n-1 not in dic:    
        dic[n-1] = countMinStepsToOne(n-1)
    return 1 + min(dic.get(n/3,MAX_VALUE),dic.get(n/2,MAX_VALUE),dic.get(n-1,MAX_VALUE))



#main
n = int(input())
print(countMinStepsToOne(n))
```

**For small values of n it is giveing correct output but when I try bigger value, lets take 5685 the powershell kill the process without output and in jupyter notebook kernel goes dead.**
According to me I think dictionary is cause problem because when I tried to print `dic` it was empty, But still not getting how it worked for smaller value not bigger ones.

Comment: Yeah, so, I do not know the origin of this problem, but when I read the problem description, it made me think about dynamic programming. I suggest using dynamic programming in order to save computation time

Comment: @Lexpj I think they are trying to use dynamic programming already.

Comment: Ah yes, I see what you mean. Though, I had something else in mind for this. Make an array of all values already, and for value, you perform one of the actions in inverse, to work bottom up instead of top down like happening here.

Comment: For integer division, use `//`, not `/`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing this recursively means you're essentially doing a DFS of the possibility space, which is going to create a very deep stack (I got a `RecursionError` when running your code on a large input) and potentially waste a lot of time computing very long paths that you'll end up recomputing later to find a shorter route to the same value.  The larger the input, the worse this effect gets.

I'd suggest doing this as a BFS instead, e.g.:

```
def steps_to_one(n):
    visited = set()
    depth = 0
    level = {n}
    while 1 not in level:
        depth += 1
        next_level = set()
        for n in level:
            if n in visited:
                continue
            visited.add(n)
            if n % 3 == 0:
                next_level.add(n // 3)
            if n % 2 == 0:
                next_level.add(n // 2)
            next_level.add(n - 1)
        level = next_level
    return depth
```

This very quickly returns the result 15 for the input 5685.

At each iteration, `level` is the current level of the search space, and `depth` is the number of levels we've traversed so far.

We keep track of `visited` so that if we end up at a value that we've already visited in a previous search path, we can ignore it quickly (e.g. if we go down the `n - 1` path and discover a value that we were already able to get to a faster way, there's no point in re-computing the path from that point).  We don't need a dict to keep track of what the depth was when we found that value, we just need to know that it's a possibility that's already in the process of being explored.

If we add a `print` to the bottom of the `while` loop:

```
print(depth, sorted(level - visited))
```

we can see what's being explored at each level of the BFS:

```
1000
1 [500, 999]
2 [250, 333, 499, 998]
3 [111, 125, 249, 332, 498, 997]
4 [37, 83, 110, 124, 166, 248, 331, 497, 996]
5 [36, 55, 62, 82, 109, 123, 165, 247, 330, 496, 995]
6 [12, 18, 31, 35, 41, 54, 61, 81, 108, 122, 164, 246, 329, 495, 994]
7 [4, 6, 9, 11, 17, 27, 30, 34, 40, 53, 60, 80, 107, 121, 163, 245, 328, 494, 993]
8 [2, 3, 5, 8, 10, 15, 16, 20, 26, 29, 33, 39, 52, 59, 79, 106, 120, 162, 244, 327, 493, 992]
9 [1, 7, 13, 14, 19, 25, 28, 32, 38, 51, 58, 78, 105, 119, 161, 243, 326, 492, 991]
9
```

Comment: Hello! I am intrigued by the choice of a `set` rather than a queue for the breadth-first-search. Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: There's no benefit to using a queue since there's no reason to explore the values in any particular order.  Using a set seems natural since we don't want to waste time on duplicates (we get most of that benefit anyway with our `visited` check, but keeping duplicates out of `level` altogether potentially shortens that `for` loop a bit) and we want to be able to check at each iteration to see if we got to 1.

Comment: Ohh I just noticed you had two sets, `level` and `next_level`. I understand now. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, since we're primarily interested in counting up the depth of the traversal, it seems easier if we search each level in its entirety and then swap (and increment our counter) as opposed to having a continuous queue.